# Non-symplectic Hamiltonian systems

Tags: coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space, poisson-brackets

I'm wondering when the phase space of a Hamiltonian system looses its symplectic structure.
I think it happens when the Hamiltonian $H$ depends on a set of other variables $S_1,...,S_k$ as well as on the set of canonical variables $q_i, p_i$.
So, besides having
$$\begin{gather}
\dot{q}_i = \bigl\{ q_i, H \bigr\} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}\\
\dot{p}_i= \bigl\{ p_i, H \bigr\} = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}
\end{gather}$$
we have also some $\dot{S}_i = \bigl\{ S_i, H \bigr\}$, which is not a Hamilton equation.

Is it right? Could anyone make this clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Well, more generally, a [Hamiltonian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_system) $\dot{z}^I=\{z^I,H\}$ with a Hamiltonian function $H:M\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined on a (not necessarily invertible) [Poisson manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_manifold) rather than a [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold).
2. A (not necessarily invertible) Poisson manifold might not have local [canonical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates)/[Darboux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem) coordinates, cf. OP's example.
3. An important example of a non-invertible Poisson bracket is the [Dirac bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket) for [constrained systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_(classical_mechanics)).